# Raspberry: Cambiar seleccionar ciclo python

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

Estoy haciendo un proyecto en el cual hay 4 motores. En dicha máquina tendra 2 o 3 modos de funcionamiento:

ECO,NORMAL,FULL

Esto, explicado, es simplemente que en ECO funcionará con 2 motores, en normal con 3 y en FULL con 4..pero no sé como programarlo.
Además lo he programado de manera que cada segundo esta comprobando el botón que hay presionado, para que cuando lo quite y seleccione el otro no tenga en cuenta el otro ciclo. (originalmente solo habia un modo y servia para parar el ciclo).

Aclarar que con un solo modo, he conseguido que funcione con otros ciclos intercalados en el qual también tiene que limpiar unos filtros mientras se paran los motores, pero con 3 modos o con 2 estoy haciendo las cosas mal y se vuelve loca la raspberry pi.

(esta conectado a un modulo de relés)

Aquí tenéis el programa:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO        # Import libreria de I/O (entradas / salidas)
import time



GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setup(29,  GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(31,  GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(33,  GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(35,  GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(37,  GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(23,  GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(3, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(5, GPIO.IN)    #MODO ECO
GPIO.setup(7, GPIO.IN)    #MODO NORMAL
GPIO.setup(10, GPIO.IN)   #MODO FULL
ON = False
OFF = True


        

def check():
  input_state = GPIO.input(5)
  return input_state and paro()

def check2()
  input_state_1 = GPIO.input(7)
  return input_state_1 and paro()

def ciclo():
  GPIO.output(29, ON)
  GPIO.output(31, ON)
  GPIO.output(37, ON)
  GPIO.output(33, OFF)
  GPIO.output(35, OFF)
  GPIO.output(23, OFF)

def eco():
  GPIO.output(29, ON)
  GPIO.output(31, ON)
  GPIO.output(37, OFF)
  GPIO.output(33, OFF)
  GPIO.output(35, OFF)
  GPIO.output(23, OFF)

def paro():
  GPIO.output(29, OFF)
  GPIO.output(31, OFF)
  GPIO.output(33, OFF)
  GPIO.output(35, OFF)
  GPIO.output(37, OFF)
  GPIO.output(23, OFF)



while True:
       ciclo()
       if check():
           break
       time.sleep(1) #1s
       eco()
       if check2():
           break
       time.sleep(1) #1s
       


 - Elemento de lista
```

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Hablas de cuatro motores, pero cuento seis (aparentemente) reles.

Comment: Tampoco explicas como el usuario selecciona el modo. ¿Con un switch o combinación?

Comment: La función `paro` no retorna nada. ¿Por qué la usas en `return input_state and paro()`?

Comment: Perdonad el desorden, el objectivo es para 4 motores, aunque el programa lo tenia escrito para 3 y me vale igualmente para buscar la solución. Efectivamente es para activar relés. Los otros 3 es para activar unos filtros pero ya es otro tema. La función paro la uso para parar los motores cuando el interruptor esta en OFF. Hasta el momento es como he sabido hacerlo, en busca de una solución mejor.

Comment: Finalmente se sustituirá el interruptor por un selector de 4 posiciones para seleccionar el modo.